# Get Published XBAP version in C#

Tags: assemblies, version, xbap

I have an XBAP currently published on my local machine, which has an 'About' canvas build into the XMAL, of which I want to show the published version number, but I can only seem to get the assembly version number.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you add the following assembly to your project references: System.Deployment. Then you can access the current version like this:

```
using System.Deployment.Application;

... 

if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    VersionTextBlock.Text = 
       ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString();
```

`CurrentDeployment` is null when you debug locally, so you can use `IsNetworkDeployed` to only retrieve the version info when you run from the published location.

Answer (score 1):

With .NET 3.0 I'm using

`Version ver = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen somewhere saying to use:

System.Deployment.ApplicationDeployment.CurrentVersion

But when using System.Deployment there appears to be no System.Deployment.ApplicationDeployment available to be accessed!

This may not be a solution but may point in the right sort of direction.  If someone uses this already maybe they can shed some more light on the matter.